# With parthenogenesis, who needs men?

Tags: story-identification, novel, sexuality

A new drug allows women to achieve orgasm AND bear children parthenogenetically without men. It's not long before men start to disappear altogether in mysterious circumstances, e.g., men who visit houses of prostitution do not survive the experience. Who needs them anyway? The last man, lured from hiding by his former partner, is preserved as a stuffed specimen in a museum.

Written in English and published by the 1970s, this novel was a misogynistic product of the Sexual Revolution.

Comment: technically that sounds like misandry not misogyny

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't make that clear. The novel was written by a man who attributed evil traits to women while playing up their sexuality. The book seems to be intended to titillate men while offending them against women. Misogynistic.

Comment: Ah I see, my mistake.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Gendercide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sex and the High Command (1970) by John Boyd

[image]

Back cover:

Dr. Henrietta Carey, leader of the Fems, was the first woman candidate for president and the perfector of VITA-LERP, a biological skin cream designed to do away with superfluous men. It spelled WAR BETWEEN THE SEXES

From [a Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/39972219?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1):

> It's contemporary 1970s America. Captain Ben Hansen of the United
>   States Navy is just returning home from an eighteen-month tour of duty
>   off Antarctica. While he's been away, a scientist by the name of Dr.
>   Henrietta Carey has perfected an orgasm-inducing parthenogenesis drug
>   marketed under the name "Vita-Lerp" and colloquially called a
>   "V-bomb." As a result, America's women are flocking to the
>   FEM—Freedom, Equality, and Motherhood—party to support Carey as a
>   presidential candidate and literally eliminate men as superfluous
>   quantities. Hansen falls in with several high-ranking military
>   officers and key cabinet members to plot how to take the United States
>   back from these crazy manslaughtering women.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you! A book review says, among other things, "Suffice it to say that in the end men are eliminated and the main male character in the book ends up stuffed in a museum - the last man on earth, so he ends up as an exhibit."
http://uncabob.blogspot.com/2014/01/sex-and-high-command.html

Answer (score 6):

The question contains what I think is the answer; [*Who Needs Men?*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1931100) by Edmund Cooper.

> Rura Alexandra, Madam Exterminator, had recently graduated into a 25th century world where men had become biologically less important, where women could reproduce as they wished by cloning and parthenogenesis.
>
> Her task was simple - in theory, if not in practice; to wipe out the last few thousand men who had taken refuge in the Highlands of Scotland.
>
> But an ambush near Loch Lomond led to rape, and the killing of her fellow-exterminators. And Diarmid MacDiarmid, the last remaining rebel chieftan proved too much of a fascination...

Comment: Wow, that looks like a trip. Surprisingly the querent didn't mention that this was also a Scottish highlander romance novel! The overlap between sexist monogender dystopias novels and Scottish highlander romance novels is very small.

Comment: Not sure. Edmund Cooper's work is certainly misogynistic enough, and based on previous questions, I'm not surprised to find this clue in the title. But the story as I remember it begins with a contemporary society of half men and half women, and only progresses to an all-female society by stages. According to Goodreads reviews, "Who Needs Men?" is set in the 25th century, not the 20th. I'm waiting for confirmation of that most striking detail, the taxidermied man at the end.

Comment: I like that word 'taxidermied'

Comment: The stuffed man is found -- but in John Boyd's Sex and the High Command, not in Who Needs Men?. (As to "taxidermied man", I used it to avoid the phrase "stuffed man," which, I am told, is mildly obscene in British English.)